# Archlinux:pip: ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'

Tags: python, pip, archlinux

Some of my python packages installed with pip had conflicts with another package I tried installing using pacman. So I decided to uninstall all the packages installed with pip. I made a requirements.txt file with all the packages and started uninstalling them. It worked fine for a while but eventually gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==10.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 479, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2703, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2321, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2327, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'
```

I got a similar error everytime I tried running pip after that.

Comment: Do you have the `requests` module installed? This seems to be a requirement of whatever code you're running. If you haven't installed `requests`, then run `pip install requests` from the command line.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I do. I tried pip install requests but got the same error.

Comment: @Joel- Just confirmed, I do have it installed.

Comment: What happens when you call `import requests`? If this raises a `ModuleNotFoundError`, then try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall requests` from the command line.

Comment: @Joel- So I tried  import requests and got  ModuleNotFoundError:  No module named 'chardet'. Then I installed chardet using pacman and tried pip again. This time I am getting: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'.

Comment: Does pip work at all on your system?

Comment: Not working at the moment.

Comment: In that case, you will need to reinstall pip

Comment: It's working now after I installed something called python-cachecontrol.

Comment: Please prefer installation with the package manager .... `pacman -S python-requests` ... Installing with `pip` does not make any sense as it produce issues the day you will install a program which will requires a python package/module ...

Comment: Yes, I only use pip under a virtualenv now.